# JWT Authentication for .net core 2.2 application not using Identity

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity

I'm following this article here: https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login and I've run into a snag where my JWT bearer token is not authorizing my user.  I get a valid JWT - See screenshot: [image]

here's a screenshot of me calling the api to retrieve that token:
[image]

And here is a screenshot of me getting a 401 in postman.
[image]

I've read through all of the comments on the article and some others were getting 401s for various reasons, but I've satisfied all of those issues and they are not mine.

Wondering if another set of eyes might help spot what's going on.  Incedentially, I'm not using `Identity` for my login stuff.  I prefer to use my own table structure and login mechanics for that but I don't think that's the source of my issue.

Here's my startup.cs file.  Anything jump out at anyone here?  Not really sure where to go next.

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string SecretKey = "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH";
    private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddDbContext<MyHomeBuilderContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyHomeBuilderContext"))
        );

        services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();

        services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        // jwt wire up
        // Get options from app settings
        var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

        // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        });

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
        });

        // api user claim policy
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
        });

        // map the email settings from appsettings.json so they can be pushed to the core project
        services.Configure<EmailSettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"))
            .AddSingleton(jd => jd.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EmailSettingsModel>>().Value);

        // map the push notification settings from appsettings.json so they can be pushed to the core project
        services.Configure<PushSettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("VapidKeys"))
            .AddSingleton(jd => jd.GetRequiredService<IOptions<PushSettingsModel>>().Value);

        services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
        services.AddTransient<IPushService, PushService>();

        services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepositoryEFDatabase>();
        services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddTransient<IAdapter<UserModel, User>, UserAdapter>();

        services.AddTransient<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepositoryEFDatabase>();
        services.AddTransient<IProjectService, ProjectService>();
        services.AddTransient<IAdapter<ProjectModel, Project>, ProjectAdapter>();

        services.AddTransient<IProjectFileBucketRepository, ProjectFileBucketRepositoryEFDatabase>();
        services.AddTransient<IProjectFileBucketService, ProjectFileBucketService>();
        services.AddTransient<IAdapter<ProjectFileBucketModel, ProjectFileBucket>, ProjectFileBucketAdapter>();

        services.AddTransient<IProjectFileRepository, ProjectFileRepositoryEFDatabase>();
        services.AddTransient<IProjectFileService, ProjectFileService>();
        services.AddTransient<IAdapter<ProjectFileModel, ProjectFile>, ProjectFileAdapter>();

        services.AddTransient<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepositoryEFDatabase>();
        services.AddTransient<IDeviceService, DeviceService>();
        services.AddTransient<IAdapter<DeviceModel, Device>, DeviceAdapter>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out. Can you post your token generation code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I greenfielded a whole new project and went through things step by step and found the culprit.  Turns out there are two actually.

1) In VS 2019 you have be debugging for the authorization to work.  Not super excited about that.  I'd much rather be able to have the authorization work with the app running but not necessarily debugging - if there's a work around for this, I'd love to hear it.
2) I had my `app.UseAuthentication()` below some of my other declarations in `Configure()` and apparently order matters - can anyone explain that?

I'll leave this up in case someone else runs into this issue and if anyone has some ideas on my questions - request I'd love to be educated :)

Comment: Ahh, yes that would make sense. For issue 2 this is how asp.net core handles middleware (and pretty much the whole pipeline is considered middleware): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2    the debugging one is just weird, surely a bug?

Comment: @Ben gotta be... and it's going to make my integration testing painful.